# RAID 6 Array Not Showing Full Drive Size with mdadm

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have an adaptec series 7 controller with 6 12TB drives. I used mdadm to create a RAID 6 array. However, when I list the array the drives show 10.7TB each rather than something closer to 12. Anyone have any ideas? I can't use MaxView as the cypher protocol does not work with any of my browsers. TIA.

Comment: 12 terabytes =
10.914 tebibytes

Comment: My bad. I meant to initialize it as RAID 5.